# My battery drains fast on my iphone-13 - is there a way to determine which app(s) have been using the most CPU in the last month?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery

just like the question says -
My battery drains fast on my iphone-13 - is there a way to determine which app(s) have been using the most CPU in the last month?

(In other words, I don't want a snapshot from just the last 10 seconds or whatever, but rather in total over the last month).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple makes it easy to see hourly for a day and daily to weekly (or thereabouts) usage.

- [About the battery usage on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201264)

I’m not aware of anything that accumulates monthly power usage but perhaps you can use screen time and correlate the week of power usage to screen time and extrapolate based on the screen time reports.

Comment: ok, how to see weekly usage?

Comment: You should get either 7 days or 10 days following the link I provided. Does your settings app work @AlexanderMills?

Comment: yes that worked, sorry didn't realize the link had that info, ty ty

Comment: Clarifying comments are always welcome. Glad it helped